# Expected states for garage

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I can't seem to find a reference in any of the SDK documentation for Google home, so my apologies if this is a super easy question that I should have found myself - I'll ask the question first then details on what my use case is -

What are the expected states from a garage door in Google home? I know "open" and "closed", but I need to know what Google expects to see when a door is opening or closing.

The use case here is a Home Assistant integration with a Meross garage door opener.  When Meross is connected directly to Google Home, both opening and closing through Google works fine. When connected through Home Assistant, Google can open the garage just fine but gives an error saying Home Assistant is unavailable when closing.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that my sensor reports closed when the garage door is closed, and immediately upon opening, the contact in the sensor breaks reporting "open." But when the garage is open, the sensor reports open until the garage has completed it's close action and the contact is re-established in the sensor (approximately 20 seconds after the close command is sent).

I worked around the issue by having Home Assistant immediately send the state of "closed" upon the close service call, but this is less than ideal.  I would imagine that Google is expecting a specific state when the garage is closing and since it is not getting that state it is timing out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the smart home platform, there are no expected states for a given device type. Rather, there are expected states for given device traits. While the [Garage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/garage) type *recommends* a single trait, it could have numerous traits with a union of those traits' states.

In particular you would be referring to the [OpenClose](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/openclose) trait. Its states would be `openPercent` as a required state and `openDirection` as an optional descriptive label. This assumes your device opens on a single axis (up/down).

In the platform, there is a short timeframe to [expect a response to the EXECUTE intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/execute), about five seconds. If it does take longer to complete the action, you may want to consider returning a status of `PENDING` rather than `SUCCESS`. That will short-circuit a response back to Assistant. You can later follow-up the confirmed change in state with [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state).

Answer (score -1):

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/01/16/google-home-hidden-api-local-devices-can-use/

google home has internal api
Please read article and find garage states.

Comment: I've used that before, but I don't see anywhere to query the expected states...where am I missing that?